# Email Function in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need a simple email function that just sends an email (not looking to spam anyone I promise!).

Anyone, anyone? Using VB 2008

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919/best-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-net-application

Answer (score 7):

Use the [**SmtpClient**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to do this.  There's an example of sending an email asynchronously on the documentation page, but here's a basic way of doing it:

```
Dim client As New SmtpClient("mail.myisp.com")

Dim fromAddr As New MailAddress("jane@contoso.com")
Dim toAddr As New MailAddress("ben@contoso.com")
Dim message As New MailMessage(fromAddr, toAddr)
message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. "
message.Subject = "test message 1"

client.Send(message)
```