# Can anyone tell me how to send how to send in .net WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, email

Can anyone tell me how to send email using WCF service.

Regards,
Giri bhushan

Comment: Woa, is your caps lock key broken?

Comment: You need to invest more effort to get an answer.

Comment: WCF is not for sending emails. You might want to have a look at the SmtpClient class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919/best-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-net-application) your question? There is nothing special about WCF in this.

(Please press your capslock)