# Emailing From .Net

Tags: c#, .net, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to send an email from a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919/best-way-to-send-an-email-from-a-net-application)

I'm developing a .NET application in C# and would like to be able to email a number of email addresses (read from a .txt file) from within side it.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?  Is there a control for this purpose or would I need to buy a 3rd party product?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with SmtpClient

```
  System.Net.NetworkCredential ncred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(EmailFrom, EmailPass);

  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(EmailFrom, EmailTo, Subject, BodyText);

  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                    {
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = ncred,
                        Timeout = 20000,
                    };
 client.SendCompleted += completeHandler;
 client.SendAsync(mail, "email");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SmtpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) to send an email from a .NET program.